Dried vs dry cooked parsley?
I just microwaved some parsley for a bit too long, it dried out and it developed a very nice and intense taste.
A lot better than dried parsley.
Just wondering what is the main difference between dried parsley and cooked dry parsley like what I have done.  is it that dry heating specifically causes the parsley to develop these flavours? I don’t believe the parsley would taste like this if you steamed, boiled or simmered it.
Thanks.

Remember that dried parsley also sits for days/months before you taste it, unlike your freshly dried stuff. Consider comparing parsley dried through your method after letting it sit around for a month against regular dried parsley - I would expect them to be much more similar.
